# How to select the size of a @OneToMany(mappedBy))collection using HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

First some context and explanation:

I have written the following HQL query:

```
select size(childGroups), size(ipts), g.id, g.name, g.status from LogicalGroup g where g.isRoot=true group by g.id, g.name, g.status
```

`LogicalGroup` is an entity with scalar fields: `id, name, status, isRoot` and two entity collection fields:

- `childGroups`

which is a

`@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentGroup")

 Set<LogicalGroup>`

`parentGroup` is another field in `LogicalGroup`. (Each group contains a set of child groups and a parent group).

and

- `ipts`

which is a

`@OneToMany(mappedBy = "logicalGroup")

 Set<IPT>`

each `IPT` has a field `logicalGroup` denoting the group that it belongs to.

What I would like the query to do, is select the size of the `childGroups` collection and the size of the `ipts` collection belonging to the root `LogicalGroup` (where `isRoot`==true). There is only ever one group for which `isRoot`==true.

Logical Group and IPT inherit their `id` fields from a superclass `AbstractEntity`. The table structure is such that there is one table per class, (the super class also has its own table). There are no join tables for the relationships between parent/child logical groups or logical group/IPT.

---

Now the question:

Firstly, I should say that the query returns the scalar values correctly.

The problem is that the query *appears* to return the size of the `LogicalGroup` set correctly, but seems to be returning the total number of `IPT`s in the `IPT` table, rather than just the ones belonging to the `LogicalGroup`. Where am I going wrong? Is something wrong with the query or potentially the mapping of the collections?

I turned on SQL logging and the following is generated and executed by Hibernate:

```
Hibernate: select count(childgroup1_.parentGroup_id) as col_0_0_, 
                  count(ipts2_.logicalGroup_id) as col_1_0_, 
                  logicalgro0_.id as col_2_0_, 
                  logicalgro0_.name >as col_3_0_, 
                  logicalgro0_.status as col_4_0_ from LogicalGroup logicalgro0_ 
           inner join AbstractEntity
                          logicalgro0_1_ on logicalgro0_.id=logicalgro0_1_.id, 
                      LogicalGroup childgroup1_, 
                      IPT ipts2_ 
           where 
                 logicalgro0_.id=childgroup1_.parentGroup_id and 
                 logicalgro0_.id=ipts2_.logicalGroup_id and 
                 logicalgro0_.isRoot=true 
           group by 
                 logicalgro0_.id , logicalgro0_.name , logicalgro0_.status
```

Comment: If I make the counts distinct:

    `select count(distinct elements(childGroups)), count(distinct elements(ipts)), g.id, g.name, g.status from LogicalGroup g where g.isRoot=true group by g.id, g.name, g.status`  

The ipts count is then correct. I still cant see why there would be duplicates returned though, any ideas?

Comment: At the point the query is executed, the `LogicalGroup` table contains 3 `LogicalGroup`s, one is the root and the other 2 are the child groups. This count (2) was returned correctly by the original query. The `IPT` table contained 1 `IPT` (belonging to the root group), but the ipt count returned 2 (duplicated result). Can anyone explain why? I think I am missing something obvious!